# Exponential Fourier transform and derivative

Tags: fourier-transform

The Fourier transform of right handed exponential function $e^{-\alpha t}$ is given by

$$\mathcal{F}\left[ e^{-\alpha t}\right] = \frac{1}{\alpha + j \omega}.$$

Its derivative is

$$\frac{d}{dt} e^{-\alpha t} = -\alpha e^{-\alpha t}.$$

So the Fourier transform of derivative is

$$\mathcal{F}\left[ \frac{d}{dt}e^{-\alpha t}\right] = -\frac{\alpha}{\alpha + j \omega}.$$

But if I use the Fourier transform derivative formula

$$j \omega F(\omega) = \frac{j \omega}{\alpha + j \omega}.$$

These results are different. Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mistake is that the derviative is

$$\dfrac{d}{dt}e^{-\alpha t}u(t) = e^{-\alpha t}\delta(t) -\alpha e^{-\alpha t}u(t)$$

From there, the rest follows and agrees with the derivative theorem of the Fourier transform.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer. Now, everything is clear. I am sorry but I could not vote up because my reputation is too low. So, I could only accept the answer.

Comment: @Stef1611: you're welcome.